# Question regarding exercise of dynamics of spin-1/2 system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

> **Problem 5) Generic Quantum-Mechanical Spin-1/2 Dynamics**
> Consider a spin-1/2 system in an external magnetic field,
> described by $H=\mu_s\mathbf{B}(t)\cdot\hat{\mathbf{S}}$ with
> $$\mathbf{B}(t) = B_0\mathbf{e}_z + B_1\left[
>  \cos(\nu t)\mathbf{e}_x + \sin(\nu t)\mathbf{e}_y\right]. \tag{1}$$
> Thus there is a static field in $z$ direction and a rotating
> field in the $x$-$y$ plane. The notation $\hat{S}_\alpha$
> refers to the dimensionless spin operator.
>
> **(a)** Write down the Schrödinger equation for $|\psi(t)\rangle$
> in the the basis $|+\rangle$, $|-\rangle$ of eigenfunctions of $S_z$.
>
> **(b)** Transform to a "rotating frame" $|\tilde{\psi}(t)\rangle
>  =\mathcal{U}(t)|\psi(t)\rangle$ using the unitary transformation
> $$\mathcal{U}(t)=\exp(i\nu t\hat{S}_z) \tag{2}$$
> Show that one obtains a time-independent problem with an
> effective Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$.

I am currently doing b) and figured that the new Schrödinger equation is $$i \hbar \mid \tilde{\psi}(t) \rangle  = (U(t) H U^{\dagger}(t) + i \hbar \dot{U}(t) U^{\dagger}(t)) \mid \tilde{\psi}(t) \rangle$$ which when writing it out with $\mid \tilde{\psi}(t) \rangle = c(t) \mid + \rangle + d(t) \mid - \rangle = e^{i \nu t} a(t) \mid + \rangle + e^{- i \nu t} b(t) \mid - \rangle = U(t) \mid \psi(t) \rangle$ turns into a coupled differential equation, but I don't see how it is time independent. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: It seems that you can edit math equations very well with MathJax. So, please replace the image by text and MathJax equations. In any case I could help you to do it.

Comment: Be careful: the question asks you to show that the *Hamiltonian* is time independent, not the state! Since you can interpret the operator on the right hand side as an effective Hamiltonian, you need to compute it explicitly

Comment: @Matteo Computing the Hamiltonian I get $\tilde{H} = \mu_B B_0 \hat{S}_z + e^{i \nu t \hat{S}_z} (\hat{S}_x \cos(\nu t) + \hat{S}_y \sin(\nu t)) e^{-i \nu t \hat{S}_z}  - \hbar \nu \hat{S}_z$ which I don't quite see being time independent because I can't simplify the term depending on $\hat{S}_x, \hat{S}_y$

Comment: @Frobenius Sadly I have never used it, I am not sure how to begin.

Comment: @goalgetter666 I think you should go ahead and compute that $e^X Y e^{-X}$ operator that you have. This formula might be very helpful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_application_of_the_identity

Comment: If I computed correctly the resulting operator is $(\hat{S}_x + i \nu t [\hat{S}_z, \hat{S}_x]) \cos(\nu t) + (\hat{S}_y + i \nu t [\hat{S}_z, \hat{S}_y]) \sin(\nu t) = (\hat{S}_x - \nu t \hat{S}_y) \cos(\nu t) + (\hat{S}_y + \nu t \hat{S}_x) \sin(\nu t)$, where the time dependence explicitally is still given for the prefactor and the trigonometric functions in my eyes

Comment: For future reference, you can find a MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do everything explicitly in the basis $\{|+\rangle,|-\rangle\}$.
So you have
$$|\psi(t)\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_+(t) \\ \psi_-(t)
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
|\tilde{\psi}(t)\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{\psi}_+(t) \\ \tilde{\psi}_-(t)
\end{pmatrix}$$

And in this basis you can write the given Hamiltonian
as a $2\times 2$-matrix
(using the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}(t)$ given by (1) and
the spin operator $\hat{\mathbf{S}}$ given by
the half [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)):

$$H(t)=\frac{1}{2}\mu_s\begin{pmatrix}
B_0 & B_1e^{-i\nu t} \\
B_1e^{i\nu t} & -B_0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Likewise you can write the operator $U(t)$ given by (2) as a matrix:
$$U(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{i\nu t/2} & 0 \\
0 & e^{-i\nu t/2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
and similarly for $U^\dagger(t)$ and $\dot{U}(t)$.

Then it is straight-forward to do the [matrix multiplications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).
Since this is homework I will leave the details to you.
You will finally arrive at
$$U(t)H(t)U^\dagger(t)
=\frac{1}{2}\mu_s\begin{pmatrix}
B_0 & B_1 \\ B_1 & -B_0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\dot{U}(t)U^\dagger(t)
=\frac{i\nu}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Insert these into your new Schrödinger's equation and you're done.

Comment: I did the calculation, thank you for the tips! but for $U(t) H(t) U^{\dagger}(t)$ I got $\frac{1}{2} \mu_s \begin{pmatrix} B_0 & B_1 \\ B_1 & - B_0 \end{pmatrix}$ since the sign came from the initial hamiltonian.

Comment: @goalgetter666 oops, you are right.